# Custom ImageView not getting instantiated java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

The following error is being thrown.

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.m.widget.CustomImageView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: accessibility
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService(BridgeContext.java:448)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsProgressBar.<init>(IcsProgressBar.java:340)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsProgressBar.<init>(IcsProgressBar.java:273)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsProgressBar.<init>(IcsProgressBar.java:269)
    at com.m2catalyst.widget.CustomImageView.<init>(CustomImageView.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:413)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:170)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
```

Comment: What device are you running this on? Personally, I think it's an overlooked once-in-a-blue-moon bug from ABS, but I'm still curious.

Comment: @Eric I have not yet run on any device it's showing the error in the Graphical layout of the XML

Comment: IcsProgressBar should be checking for `View.isInEditMode()` before trying to access the Accessibility Service from the context, but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message tells you what is going on:

> at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsProgressBar.(IcsProgressBar.java:340

that doesn't play well with the UI Editor you're using. Do this:

```
public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}


public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    imageView = new ImageView(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if (!isInEditMode()) progressBar = new IcsProgressBar(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}
```

something like that should help. Basically check if the view is in a UI editor with isInEditoMode and don't run code that isn't supported in that mode.